# Accessing external function from a class defined in the same file

Tags: c++, class, function

If I have a class definition

```
class myClass
{
  void x(); 
};


void myClass::x()
{
   hello(); // error: ‘hello’ was not declared in this scope
}

void hello()
{
   cout << "Hello\n" << endl;
}
```

How can I call a function defined outside the scope of a class and located in the same file ? I know that I can use `Namespace::function` but I am not sure in this case what I should use for `Namespace`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must at least declare it (if not define it) before its use.

Usually, this is done in an anonymous namespace if the function's functionality is only used in that translation unit:

```
class myClass
{
  void x(); 
};

namespace
{
   void hello()
   {
      cout << "Hello\n" << endl;
   }
}

void myClass::x()
{
   hello(); // error: ‘hello’ was not declared in this scope
}
```

This gives the function internal linkage (similar to declaring it `static`) and is only available in that TU.

Answer (score 4):

Define the `hello` function in the file ahead of where it's being used - *before* method `x` - **or** supply a function prototype ahead of where it's being used:

```
void hello();  // function definition is later in the file

void myClass::x()
{
   hello();
}
```